# Upgraded Alfresco community edition 5.0 to 5.1 Search functionality not working?

Tags: java, lucene, alfresco, solr4

I upgraded Alfresco community edition 5.0 to 5.1 and search is not working anymore.

I am getting following error,

> 2016-05-05 05:16:26,175 ERROR [org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid Number: java
>       at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.readableToIndexed(TrieField.java:409)
>       at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.readableToIndexed(TrieField.java:379)
>       at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.toInternal(TrieField.java:416)
>       at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType$DefaultAnalyzer$1.incrementToken(FieldType.java:473)
>       at org.alfresco.solr.query.Solr4QueryParser.getFieldQueryImpl(Solr4QueryParser.java:1273)
>       at org.alfresco.solr.query.Solr4QueryParser.getFieldQueryImplWithIOExceptionWrapped(Solr4QueryParser.java:827)
>       at org.alfresco.solr.query.Solr4QueryParser.getSuperFieldQuery(Solr4QueryParser.java:3724)
>       at org.alfresco.solr.query.Solr4QueryParser$FieldQuery.getQuery(Solr4QueryParser.java:3822)
>       at org.alfresco.solr.query.Solr4QueryParser.attributeQueryBuilder(Solr4QueryParser.java:4238)
>       at org.alfresco.solr.query.Solr4QueryParser.getFieldQuery(Solr4QueryParser.java:625)
>       at org.alfresco.solr.query.Lucene4QueryParserAdaptor.getFieldQuery(Lucene4QueryParserAdaptor.java:67)
>       at org.alfresco.solr.query.Lucene4QueryParserAdaptor.getFieldQuery(Lucene4QueryParserAdaptor.java:48)
>       at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.querymodel.impl.lucene.functions.LuceneFTSTerm.addComponent(LuceneFTSTerm.java:68)
>       at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.querymodel.impl.lucene.LuceneFunctionalConstraint.addComponent(LuceneFunctionalConstraint.java:57)
>       at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.querymodel.impl.lucene.LuceneDisjunction.addComponent(LuceneDisjunction.java:65)
>       at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.querymodel.impl.lucene.LuceneQuery.buildQuery(LuceneQuery.java:105)
>       at org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoSolrDataModel.getFTSQuery(AlfrescoSolrDataModel.java:2321)
>       at org.alfresco.solr.query.AlfrescoFTSQParserPlugin$AlfrescoFTSQParser.parse(AlfrescoFTSQParserPlugin.java:94)
>       at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:141)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:147)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.component.AlfrescoSearchHandler.handleRequestBody(AlfrescoSearchHandler.java:283)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1976)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.alfresco.web.scripts.servlet.X509ServletFilterBase.doFilter(X509ServletFilterBase.java:144)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Could you please specify from with particular version you started? 5.0.d? Along with the version you're going to. Also specify which steps you followed in order to perform the upgrade.

Comment: I upgraded Alfresco 5.0.d to 5.1.0 (r122274-b3) I followed by this link(http://fcorti.com/2014/07/17/alfresco-upgrade-tutorial-4-0-d-to-4-2-f/) in this link 4.0.d  to 4.2.f i followed steps

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should re-index. [Here](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/solr-reindex.html) are the steps.

Comment: What is the query you are running that is causing the error?

Comment: Just i have search the word for example "JAVA" i am getting above error but when search field giving any numeric numbers its working fine, won't causing errors

Comment: What version of the JDK are you running? Is it the one that shipped with Alfresco or one that you installed?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)